# Save values of any type

Tags: rust

I try to save changes of struct fields in boxed struct `ValuesChangingImpl<T>` and hide fields type under trait `ValuesChanging` with code:

```
use std::any::Any;
use std::clone::Clone;

//#[derive(Clone)]
pub enum HistoryItem {
    FieldChanging(Box<ValuesChanging>)
    // other changing variants
}

pub trait ValuesChanging/*: Clone*/ {
    fn get_old_value<T: Any + Clone>(&self) -> &T;
    fn get_new_value<T: Any + Clone>(&self) -> &T;
}

pub struct ValuesChangingImpl<T> where T: Any + Clone {
    old_value: Box<T>,
    new_value: Box<T>
}

impl<T:Any + Clone> ValuesChangingImpl<T> {
    pub fn new(old_value: Box<T>, new_value: Box<T>) -> Self {
        ValuesChangingImpl {
            old_value: old_value,
            new_value: new_value
        }
    }
}

impl<T:Any + Clone> Clone for ValuesChangingImpl<T> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        ValuesChangingImpl::new(
            self.old_value.clone(),
            self.new_value.clone())
    }
}

impl<T:Any + Clone> ValuesChanging for ValuesChangingImpl<T> {
    fn get_old_value<ValueType: Any + Clone>(&self) -> &ValueType {
        self.old_value.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()
    }

    fn get_new_value<ValueType: Any + Clone>(&self) -> &ValueType {
        self.new_value.downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap()
    }
}
```

Compilation of this code fail with error:

```
error: the trait `ValuesChanging` cannot be made into an object [--explain E0038]
 --> <anon>:6:19
6 |>     FieldChanging(Box<ValuesChanging>)
  |>                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: method `get_old_value` has generic type parameters
note: method `get_new_value` has generic type parameters
```

If uncomment adding `Clone` trait

```
error: the trait `ValuesChanging` cannot be made into an object [--explain E0038]
 --> <anon>:6:23
6 |>         FieldChanging(Box<ValuesChanging>)
  |>                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
note: the trait cannot require that `Self : Sized`
```

As I understand, the cause is attempt of using `trait` (as unsized type on stack) in a field itself. But what is the reason when I put it into `Box`?

Is it just not implemented in type system of Rust or there is more fundamental reason of those errors?
Is there other options to implement this behavior?

Comment: @antoyo: Indeed, well spotted.

Comment: Thanks! I forget about necessity lifetime for traits.